# JQuery not being loaded in rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently, it seems as though my jquery and other js files aren't being included in my views..

I have this gem in my gem file:

gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'

I'm using rails 3.1.0

in my header is:

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

The html coming through the view is this:

```
<head>
  <link href="/assets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/defaults.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="scIP+mIH7ON1DYP9XWeSidk/5i4DizpuwQOP8mcxA9M=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

in my config/application.rb file I also have:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In rails 3.1, you want this instead:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

That way it'll use the asset pipeline. Without it, it's looking for all.css and defaults.js

Comment: Correct. Looks like OP still has `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`